# Why does my DecisionTreeClassifier model complain that the labelCol does not exist when predicting?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I'm beginning to write an ML model for classification of paragraphs in a series of documents. I wrote my model and the results look great! However, when I try feeding a CSV that does not contain the labelCol (i.e. the tagged column, the column I'm trying to predict), it throws an error! 'Field tagIndexed does not exist.'

So this is odd. What I'm trying to predict is the "tag" column, so why would it expect a "tagIndexed" column when I call `model.transform(df)` (in Predict.scala)? I'm not experienced with ML, but the all DecisionTreeClassifiers tend to have the labelCol nonexistent in the testing data. What am I missing here?

I created the model, validated it with testing data, and saved it to disk. Then, in another Scala object, I load the model and pass my csv into it.

```
//Train.scala    
package com.secret.classifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, IDF, StringIndexer, Tokenizer, VectorAssembler, Word2Vec}
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, TrainValidationSplit}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.types
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}

...

val colSeq = Seq("font", "tag")
val indexSeq = colSeq.map(col => new StringIndexer().setInputCol(col).setOutputCol(col+"Indexed").fit(dfNoNan))

val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("soup").setOutputCol("words")
//val wordsData = tokenizer.transform(dfNoNan)

val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
.setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol)
.setOutputCol("rawFeatures")
.setNumFeatures(20)

val featuresCol = "features"
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
.setInputCols((numericCols ++ colSeq.map(_+"Indexed")).toArray)
.setOutputCol(featuresCol)

val labelCol = "tagIndexed"
val decisionTree = new DecisionTreeClassifier()
.setLabelCol(labelCol)
.setFeaturesCol(featuresCol)

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages((indexSeq :+ tokenizer :+ hashingTF :+ assembler :+ decisionTree).toArray)

val Array(training, test) = dfNoNan.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed=420420)

val model = pipeline.fit(training)


model.write.overwrite().save("tmp/spark-model")

//Predict.scala
package com.secret.classifier
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, IDF, StringIndexer, Tokenizer, VectorAssembler, Word2Vec}
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, TrainValidationSplit}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}

...

  val dfImport = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  //.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .schema(customSchema)
  .load(csvLocation)

val df = dfImport.drop("_c0", "doc_name")
df.show(20)

val model = PipelineModel.load("tmp/spark-model")

val predictions = model.transform(df)

predictions.show(20)


//pom.xml -> Spark/Scala specific dependencies
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
    <spec2.version>4.2.0</spec2.version>
</properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-csv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.univocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>univocity-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The expected result is that the predictions model not throw an error. Instead, it throws the error 'Field "tagIndexed" does not exist.'

Comment: Please include explicitly your *imports* and your Spark version

Comment: @desertnaut done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've included the label field in your features also since it is in the colSeq column outputs.  In this step, you only want to include feature columns:

```
.setInputCols((numericCols ++ colSeq.map(_+"Indexed")).toArray)
```

I find it helpful to use .filterNot() function.

Comment: I think that's the bug, haha! I knew it had to do something with the VectorAssembler. Probably bleeds into my training data too. I'll do this fix and I'm sure it'll work!

Comment: So I used .filterNot() as you suggested and that worked perfectly. I then had an error about the StringIndexer struggling with null values (as the column does not exist in the testing data), but passing .setHandleInvalid("skip") after .setOutputCol() and before .fit() works perfectly as well! 

Note for anyone viewing this question in the future: plan out ahead of time how you will handle training data with missing columns and values!